# Testing Error System seems to not recognize test class

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, failing-tests

> **ERROR:**  Unable to run tests synchronously: [This class name's value is
>   invalid: Opportunity_EmailServiceTest. Provide the name of an Apex
>   class that has test methods.].

```
@isTest
private class Opportunity_EmailServiceTest{

//@isTest static void test_matching_product() {
    ////send fake email
    //Messaging.InboundEmail email = new Messaging.InboundEmail();
    //email.fromAddress = userInfo.getUserEmail();
    //email.subject = 'TestCode123';
    ////create an attachment
    //Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment att = new Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment();
    //att.fileName = 'TestAttachment';
    //att.Body = Blob.valueOf('Test123');
    //email.binaryAttachments = new List<Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment>{att};
    //Opportunity_EmailService serv = new Opportunity_EmailService();
    //test.startTest();
    //Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = serv.handleInboundEmail(email, null);
    //test.stopTest();
//}

@isTest static void testCreateOppSingle(){
    //send fake email
    Messaging.InboundEmail email = new Messaging.InboundEmail();
    email.fromAddress = userInfo.getUserEmail();
    email.subject = 'TestCode123';
    //create an attachment
    Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment att = new Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment();
    att.fileName = 'TestAttachment';
    att.Body = Blob.valueOf(
        TestDataFactory.getCsvData()
    );
    email.binaryAttachments = new List<Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment>{att};
    Opportunity_EmailService serv = new Opportunity_EmailService();
    test.startTest();
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = serv.handleInboundEmail(email, null);
    test.stopTest();
    Opportunity createdOpp = [Select Id, Name, Amount, StageName, CloseDate from Opportunity limit 1];
    System.assertEquals(createdOpp.Name, 'Test Opportunity Name');
    System.assertEquals(createdOpp.Amount, 100000);
    System.assertEquals(createdOpp.StageName, 'Closed Won');
    System.assertEquals(createdOpp.CloseDate, '2018-01-01:00:00');
}
}
```

Class being tested.

```
global class Opportunity_EmailService implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
public Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope env) {
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();

    //try{
        List<Opportunity> oppsToUpsert = new List<Opportunity>();
        for(Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment att : email.binaryAttachments){

            String attBody = att.Body.toString();
            for(String row : attBody.split('\r\n')) {
                String oppData = row.split(',');
                Opportunity o = new Opportunity();

                o.Name = oppData[0];

                String dateConcat = oppData[1] + ':' + 00 + ':' + 00;
                o.CloseDate = dateConcat;

                o.Amount = Integer.valueOf(oppData[3]);

                o.StageName = oppData[2];
            }
            oppsToUpsert.add(o);
            //}
        }

    //}
    //catch(Exception e){
    //  system.debug(e);
    //  system.debug(e.getStackTraceString());
    //}
    return result;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. A number of errors here. My code in the class isn't in a method. Also typecasting error on oppData. oppstoupsert needs to be in that last for loop etc etc. Disregard.